# Android GridView not rendering properly

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am looking to create a grid view in the following manner using the following code :

GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e5e5e5" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:columnWidth="190dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

with grid item as :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_card" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But the result is something like this :

[image]

[image]

Hence, my question is this :

1. In the first image, the right column is right along the edge of the screen and there is a lot of empty space between the 2 columns. I have tried changing the padding and margins but it didnt work. How do I make the spacing uniform ?
2. In the second image, the last few items of the grid do not get displayed at all  and even the last 2 items are cut-out at the bottom. What is the mistake I am making here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its not letting you scroll to see the last two items, or you want all 6 items to fit on screen at once?

Comment: its not letting me scroll. I have many more items, but it is not letting me scroll further down

Comment: ok it appears in the second image you were able to scroll down some (i see the bottom of some previous images).  The images that were "cut out" aren't displayed at all?

Comment: for the second point remove the " padding="5dp" ". Padding is for the inside, margin is for the outside.

Comment: Yes the ones that were cut out arent displayed at all

Comment: ok its almost certain the error is your adapter.  Post the adapter code, particularly the "getCount" method.

Comment: Tsuzane, removing the padding gives the same problem